# What happens when I rename the parent directory of a git repo?

Tags: git, rename, git-repo

If I have a git repo in a folder named `some-folder`, and I change it to `another-folder`, is there going to be any problems?

Comment: No, git doesn't know the name of the folder it's in. All of the information relative to the git setup is in the .git/ folder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer here is both no and yes.

In many (most?) cases, Git will have no issues at all, as Git works relative to the top level of the working tree and the `.git` directory.

When using `git worktree`, however, and/or when the repository may be referred-to by other users as a *remote*—for instance, when you're on a server that *serves* Git requests—it's possible that there are absolute path references to that particular repository.  If so, any references outside the repository itself will need to be updated.  For instance, if you're working with the Git repository on your company's main Git server, and it resides in `/exports/repos/path/to/repo.git` and you change this to `/exports/repos/repository.git`, it's likely that everyone in the company must change their URLs from `ssh://example.com/path/to/repo.git` to `ssh://example.com/repository.git`.

So, the answer is to pay attention to the surrounding context in which the repository is *used*.  Git itself is not likely to have issues here, but *other people* might.  If you are using extra work-trees, consider how they may be affected, too.